# How to find length of string in shell

Tags: shell, shell-script, sh

I need to calculate the length of a string using pure sh shell only. What is happening is that `/bin/sh` is actually a soft link to bash or another shell. Hence `${#STRING}` gives the length of string as it is advance bash feature.

Can someone tell me how I can find length of string?
I am using Solaris 5.10 Sparc architecture

Comment: It is not an advanced bash feature. The ${#STRING} parameter expension is [defined by posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). And it also works under `dash` which is a POSIX compliant shell without bash-only features.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`wc -m` counts the chars in a string. So you can do something like:

```
STRLENGTH=$(echo -n $STRING | wc -m)
```

Alternative syntax:

```
STRLENGTH=`echo -n $STRING | wc -m`
```

The `-n` flag for echo stops it from printing a newline. The flag might be different on Solaris 5. Check `man echo`

Comment: Finally something that might work. **Except it won't**, because it will add trailing newline, which will be counted by `wc`. And there is no portable way to suppress it! Some shells use `-n` parameter, some use some escape sequence and neither is specified in POSIX.

Comment: It does not has to be portable. It must only work under Solaris 5.10. But you are right. I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: i should then do LEN-1 to get original length  right?

Comment: can you suggest a way that will work on any linux or unix platform?

Comment: If you substract 1 from the length its more portable than using the `-n` flag.

Comment: @Niraj: Use `printf` instead of `echo`. It should exist everywhere too and works everywhere the same.

Comment: i am new in this ..can you give me syntax to use printf?

Comment: @Niraj: I did in my answer.

Comment: @Niraj: Does your shell understand `let` or arithmetic substitution? `expr` is older way for that and if you don't even have `expr`, I wouldn't expect arithmetic substitution either.

Comment: i want way which will work throughout any unix/linux platform?

Comment: In this case the printf solution is probably the best. `STRLENGTH=$(printf "%s" $STRING | wc -m)`

Comment: syntax error: `STRLENGTH=$' unexpected getting error on sh 4.10 version

Comment: you can try the alternative syntax Instead of using `$()` you can use two backticks `

Comment: Instead of -n and -m, why not -L ? It will count spaces in the string but **will not** newlines.

Answer (score 17):

Here are couple of ways to do it.

```
myvar="This is a test"
echo "${#myvar}"
14
```

Or

```
expr length "${myvar}"
14
```

Answer (score 9):

Using `${#string}` to get the length of `$string` is [a POSIX shell parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/).  It is not a `bash`-only feature.

On Solaris 5.10, if `/bin/sh` or `/usr/bin/sh` (as mentioned in the [`sh(1)`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/sunos/1/sh/) manual) does not support this, then `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` will.

To get POSIX behaviour on a Solaris 5.10 system, your `PATH` should be set to

```
/usr/xpg6/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin
```

(in that order), as described in the [`standards(5)` manual](https://www.unix.com/man-page/sunos/5/standards/).

Answer (score 3):

Here is couple of ways :

```
echo ${#VAR}
echo -n $VAR | wc -m
echo -n $VAR | wc -c
printf $VAR | wc -m
expr length $VAR
expr $VAR : '.*'
```

http://techopsbook.blogspot.in/2017/09/how-to-find-length-of-string-variable.html

Comment: (1) Six is not a “couple”.  (2) These are not equivalent.  Please explain the differences.

Comment: These are couple if you count equivalent as single.

Comment: 1) echo ${#VAR} 2)echo -n $VAR | wc -m, echo -n $VAR | wc -c, printf $VAR | wc -m 3)expr length $VAR ,expr $VAR : '.*'

Comment: There's a lot of variation in how "couple" is used. No need to shame users for their language use, especially in cases where native speakers will have differing views of what's acceptable. Anyway, off topic - leave that to https://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "pure sh" can do it. But you don't need to do anything in "pure sh"; you need to do it in sh plus standard utilities. The most straightforward way is:

```
strlength=`expr "$string" : ".*"`
```

([expr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expr.html) is POSIX). Or if you don't have `expr` (Solaris 5.1 is ancient), you could also use [wc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/wc.html) together with [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html) like:

```
strlength=`printf "%s" "$string" | wc -m`
```

Just don't try to use `echo`, because echo will add trailing newlines and there is no standard way to suppress it.

Note that `wc -m` counts characters and `wc -c` counts bytes if there is a difference in current locale.

Comment: it will not work under sparc arcitecture

Comment: @Niraj: What won't work under Solaris? They don't have `expr`? Do they have `printf` and `wc`?

Comment: I think `-c` counts the bytes of the string. This will probably not  give you the correct value if you are using a multibyte characterset.

Comment: @PeterLamby: You are right. `-m` is probably better here.

Comment: @Niraj: Adjusted the process substitution to backticks; (pre-POSIX) bourne shell didn't have `$()` process substitution.

Answer (score 1):

*(Though there are already many answers, but feels they are not so intuitive, so I would add one to make it clear on first sight)*

If you just want to do it in shell *(bash)* command line *(or even script)*.

You can use either of following ways:

- Use `echo -n` and `wc -m`
- Use `printf` and `wc -m`

**e.g**

```
# 5
echo -n hello | wc -m

# 11
echo -n "hello world" | wc -m

# 5
printf "hello" | wc -m

# 11
printf "hello world" | wc -m

# 11
printf "hello %s" world | wc -m
```

**Tips:**

- `echo` by default will append a new line at end, so `-n` option is needed to avoid that.
- If there are space among input string, then should quote it.

Answer (score 1):

using awk:  Works from any type of shell

set xxx = "12345"

echo $xxx | awk '{ print length }'

5

Answer (score -1):

> set var="test test test";
>
> echo $%var;
>
> 14

Comment: i do not get it

Answer (score -2):

You could do this fairly simply in python

```
>>> len('hello world')
11
```

Comment: In theory, you could run python as/in a shell. That said, it looks like their string is a environmental variable and a more complete answer would take that into account. Also, whether such an old version of solaris would have python - notice Kusalanada's answer which goes into the... oddities of that particular flavour of unix